# exec() system call in Linux

Tags: linux, c, system-calls

Accoding to this [link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html), we need to terminate the list of argumnets by a null pointer. This is stated as :

> The list of arguments must be terminated by a null pointer.

My question is why we need to terminate the list of argument by a null pointer ? Is this used because to know the end of the list of argument, which is an array to char pointers ?

Comment: you're assumption seems correct

Comment: Yes. Also, where the function declaration calls for environment arguments (envp list), that list too must be terminated by another NULL pointer, even when the envp list is otherwise empty. All these Section 3 functions are a thin layer that maps onto the execve() call, which is a Section 2 (system call) action, and has a rather better and more complete description of the interface.

Comment: Agreeing with my two previous commenters; this is done to know the end of the list. There's an interesting historical question there, which is why they chose to go the less space efficient, less safe way of zero termination instead of adding another length parameter, but alas, one can assume they must have expected programmers to be aware of C string pitfalls, so that this was at least consistent.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Notably, the `argv` list passed through `execve()` eventually gets placed on the new process's stack, and the call to `main()` has magically gained an `argc`. I always wondered why there is no `envc`. Seems to me that before `getenv()` existed, `argc` was just an optimization to enable an `envp` name search to know where `envp[0]` was.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yeah, I always wondered the converse: Since there's an `argc`, why bother having the terminating zero pointer in `argv`? People talking to me about the strength and weaknesses of the C language and its explicit and cultural descendants know that I'm not at all, even remotely, a friend of the C string. It's been a bad idea in 1969, and it's still one of the, if not *the*, most common reason for software buffer bugs. It solves a problem nobody actually cares about, with a solution that's bad for software quality and speed.

Comment: (legend has it the zero-terminated string was invented to avoid wasting a full word on just knowing how long a string is, since `char` can be much shorter than a word. However, whenever you're dealing with isolated strings, you can be almost certain that external alignment constrains at least suggest you should be starting your string at a `int*`-granular address, not at any `char* address, so that the hypothetical benefit of saving `sizeof(int) - 1` bytes of memory shrinks in practice. I can program a loop, or even better, my DMA controller, to copy N bytes. intel introduced special …

Comment: … instructions just to make tight "until you hit the zero byte" loops more efficient (largely obsolete due to better compilers and pipelines, and still way less efficient than knowing how often you need to do something, because your string has known length). Finally, one could argue that for where the amount of size saved by a terminating `char` instead of a length-defining `int`, when you got many short strings, you could have done something like "lengths smaller than 128 represent the string length in `uint8_t`; if the MSB in length is set, big-endian preceding byte for long string support")

Comment: In a way, null-terminated arrays are ok if you access the data from start to end anyway. But if you need to know the length for e.g. a memory allocation, then it's not that ok... If the syscall had more arguments, the total number of args could also start being an issue, it at least looks ugly in the code and there might be some issues if a fixed set of registers is used to pass the args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we need to terminate the list of argument by a null pointer? Is this used because to know the end of the list of argument, which is an array to char pointers?

Yes. Same for the array of environment variables. The kernel needs to know somehow how much data to copy from the calling process and the system call doesn't take an explicit argument for the number of elements in those arrays. (Passing that as an explicit argument would of course also work.)

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, there is no `exec()` system call. `exec()` is a notation used to refer to a family of related APIs: the `execve()` *system call* and a set of *library functions* layered on top of that system call. The library functions provide small API variations that are often useful.

*Some* of the *library functions*--the ones with an `l` in the suffix of the function name--are variadic functions. They allow you to specify the command-line arguments of the program that will be executed as a list (of *arbitrary* length) in the function call. The null pointer at the end of that list allows the function to determine where the end of that list is. (Just where these arguments are stored is implementation dependent. See [Are va_arg arguments to functions stored in stack or heap memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164562/are-va-arg-arguments-to-functions-stored-in-stack-or-heap-memory))

The library function internally allocates an `argv` array of the right size and populates that array with pointers to the string (and adds a `NULL` as the last element of that `argv`). The constructed `argv` is then (ultimately) passed in a call to `execve()`.